# data did not display when ajax called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to display the data from php by using ajax
I check the connection by using `success: function(){alert(""success)} :`,so there is no problem with the connection.
But the data did not display. 
here is the ajax code.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    'use strict';
   //this line works!
   //$('#JSONoffers').load('getOffers.php?useJSON')

      //try to get data using .ajax()method
       $.ajax({ 
           dataType: "json",           
           url: "getOffers.php?useJSON",    
            success: function(data){
        $('#JSONoffers').html(data);
  },
    error:function(){
        alert("Fail");
    }  
});     
})
```

here is partial html code (script included)

```
<aside  id="JSONoffers"> </aside>
```

There is no error in the console.
Is there any mistake?

Edited for arrange the data in

format 
so i added the following code to change the output format

```
 $.ajax({ 
           dataType: "json",           
           url: "getOffers.php?useJSON",    

            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
        //$('#JSONoffers').append(JSON.stringify(data))

        var $li, $ul = $('<ul>');
        for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
            $li = $('<li>').text(data[i].eventTitle);
            $li = $('<li>').text(data[i].catDesc);  
            $li = $('<li>').text(data[i].eventPrice);           //include other props here
            $ul.append($li);
}
        $('#JSONoffers').html($ul[0].outerHTML)
  },
    error:function(){
        alert("Fail");
    }  
});
```

Since the data type is in JSON, `append(JSON.stringify(data))` is used. 
However, why `$('#JSONoffers').html($ul[0].outerHTML)`, `.html()` is used instead  `append(JSON.stringify(data))`. 
Also, after i applied the code that tried to display in `ul`, the data did not display.

Comment: What do you see in the console if you `console.log(data)` as the first line of your `success` handler? Also, if the data is in JSON format, why would you treat it as HTML and display it using `.html(data)`? That makes no sense.

Comment: use console.log(data) to inspect data.

Comment: ok, i added the `console.log(data)` in the success handle, and i saw the data on my console. And i remove the `dataType:"json" ` and the data displayed! thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html()` expects *markup*. `$('#JSONoffers').html(data)` will do nothing since you are in fact passing JSON. If you want to inject the JSON you should do

```
$('#JSONoffers').text(data)
```

This will (probably) cause inserted content on the form `[object Object]` etc. So `stringify()` before injecting :

```
$('#JSONoffers').text(JSON.stringify(data))
```

---

Inserting JSON items as `<ul><li></li></ul>`, small example :

```
var $li, $ul = $('<ul>');
for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {
   $li = $('<li>').text(data[i].eventTitle); //include other props here
   $ul.append($li);
}
$('#JSONoffers').html($ul[0].outerHTML)
```

Comment: it's help! Thanks! now the data displayed `{eventTitle: "Little Black Rose Musical Variety Show", catDesc: "Music", eventPrice: "8.00"}`. Is the any method to let the data display in `<ul><li>` format without changing the php